# Accengage: Push notifications not working

Tags: android, push-notification, push

We have migrated from GCM to FCM on Accengage in Android. I can receive test Push Notifications from the portal with type "test segment" and in the segments it shows the users.

But when I change the type of the segment to "real" it won't send the Push Notification on device.

What could be the reason for not sending Push Notifications on a "real segments" while everything is working fine on "test segment"?

Answer (score 0):

After several hit & trials and getting in touch with Accengage helpline I was finally able to send Push Notification on "Real Segments".

The problem was with the **"Marketing Pressure"**. 
According to the Accengage feedback:

*​- The marketing pressure is activated for your environnement : 1 push per day*

So, I just disable the **"Marketing Pressure"** while creating a Push Notification 
Message and it **worked**!!

.[image]